# Read a matrix from a file

Tags: c

This is my function to read a matrix from a file. In the text file I have on the first line 2 is `n` and  3 is `m` and  on the next two lines is the matrix. 
I don't have erros, but my program "stop working" and I don't know why. Thank you!
In main I have: `readmatrix(n,m,a, "text.txt");`

```
int readmatrix(int* n,int *m, int a[*n][*m], char* filename){
    FILE *pf;
    int i,j;
    pf = fopen (filename, "rt");
    if (pf == NULL)
    return 0;
    fscanf (pf, "%d",n); 
    for (i=0;i<*n;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<*m;j++)
        fscanf (pf, "%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
    fclose (pf); 
    return 1; 
    }
```

Comment: `int a[*n][*m]`? Does it really compile?

Comment: Yes...So..there is the mistake? How it's right?

Comment: A variable-length array (VLA) is not going to help much with this case. `int a[*n][*m]` isn't an "afterthought". Changing the values `n` and `m` point to won't magically make `a` resize to be a correct VLA. That is the fundamental problem. It will code to whatever `n` and `m` point to on entry, which won't work for you with the given function task (read both the dimensions and the values).

Comment: `int readmatrix(int* n,int *m, int (*a)[n][m], char* filename){` For this I have the error "Size of array a has no integer type".

Answer (score 5):

If your compiler supports VLAs or you are using C99, then you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int readmatrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*a)[cols], const char* filename)
{

    FILE *pf;
    pf = fopen (filename, "r");
    if (pf == NULL)
        return 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            fscanf(pf, "%d", a[i] + j);
    }


    fclose (pf); 
    return 1; 
}

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[2][3];

    readmatrix(2, 3, matrix, "file.dat");

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            printf("%-3d ", matrix[i][j]);
        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`file.dat` looks like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

and the output of my program is

```
$ ./a 
1   2   3   
4   5   6
```

Note that this is a basic example, you should always check the return value of
`fscanf`. If `file.dat` had one row only, then you would get in trouble. Also
there are not numbers in the file, you would get also undefined values in the
matrix.

I'd advice to read the whole line with `fgets` and then parse the line using
`sscanf` or some other function like `strtok`, then it would be easier to react
to errors in the input file.

---

**edit**

A more robust way of reading a file like this would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>


int **readmatrix(size_t *rows, size_t *cols, const char *filename)
{
    if(rows == NULL || cols == NULL || filename == NULL)
        return NULL;

    *rows = 0;
    *cols = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    int **matrix = NULL, **tmp;

    char line[1024];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        if(*cols == 0)
        {
            // determine the size of the columns based on
            // the first row
            char *scan = line;
            int dummy;
            int offset = 0;
            while(sscanf(scan, "%d%n", &dummy, &offset) == 1)
            {
                scan += offset;
                (*cols)++;
            }
        }

        tmp = realloc(matrix, (*rows + 1) * sizeof *matrix);

        if(tmp == NULL)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            return matrix; // return all you've parsed so far
        }

        matrix = tmp;

        matrix[*rows] = calloc(*cols, sizeof *matrix[*rows]);

        if(matrix[*rows] == NULL)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            if(*rows == 0) // failed in the first row, free everything
            {
                fclose(fp);
                free(matrix);
                return NULL;
            }

            return matrix; // return all you've parsed so far
        }

        int offset = 0;
        char *scan = line;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < *cols; ++j)
        {
            if(sscanf(scan, "%d%n", matrix[*rows] + j, &offset) == 1)
                scan += offset;
            else
                matrix[*rows][j] = 0; // could not read, set cell to 0
        }

        // incrementing rows
        (*rows)++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return matrix;
}

int main(void)
{

    size_t cols, rows;
    int **matrix = readmatrix(&rows, &cols, "file.dat");

    if(matrix == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not read matrix\n");
        return 1;
    }


    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            printf("%-3d ", matrix[i][j]);
        puts("");

    }


    // freeing memory
    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Now `file.dat` looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 
4 5 6 5 
9 8 8 7 
5 5 5 5 
1 1 1 1
```

And the output is

```
1   2   3   4   
4   5   6   5   
9   8   8   7   
5   5   5   5   
1   1   1   1
```

In this example I calculate the number of columns only for the first column and
use that number for all other columns. If the input file has rows with less
columns that the first row, then the missing values are stored with 0. If it has rows with
more columns than the row will be trimmed.

I calculate the number of rows like this:

```
            while(sscanf(scan, "%d%n", &dummy, &offset) == 1)
            {
                scan += offset;
                (*cols)++;
            }
```

First I declare a pointer `scan` to point to `line`, so that I can modify the
pointer without losing the original line. The `%n` in `sscanf` is not counted in
the number of successfull conversions, this returns the position of `scan` where
it stopped reading. I used that to loop the `sscanf`. I explicitly check that
`sscanf` returns 1 and if that's the case, I increment the number of columns and
I update `scan` to update to the point where `sscanf` stoppped reading. This
allows me to continue scanning until the end of the line is reached. I use a
similar technique to parse all the integers.

Comment: Thank you.But I still have a question. Is there any possibility to get the number of colons and rows from the text/dat file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid of using `goto`, an easy-to-read, robust way to read a matrix looks like this:

```c
typedef struct Matrix
{
    size_t width, height;
    double **data;
} Matrix;

Matrix read_matrix(char const *filename)
{
    Matrix matrix;
    FILE *file;

    if ((file = fopen(filename, "rt")) == NULL)
        goto error;

    if (fscanf(file, "%zu %zu", &matrix.width, &matrix.height) != 2)
        goto error_file;

    if ((matrix.data = (double **)calloc(matrix.height, sizeof(double *))) == NULL)
        goto error_file;

    for (size_t y = 0; y < matrix.height; ++y)
        if ((matrix.data[y] = (double *)malloc(matrix.width * sizeof(double))) == NULL)
            goto error_matrix;

    for (size_t y = 0; y < matrix.height; ++y)
        for (size_t x = 0; x < matrix.width; ++x)
            if (fscanf(file, "%lf", &matrix.data[y][x]) != 1)
                goto error_matrix;

    fclose(file);
    return matrix;

error_matrix:
    for (size_t y = 0; y < matrix.height; ++y)
        free(matrix.data[y]);
    free(matrix.data);

error_file:
    fclose(file);

error:
    return (Matrix){0, 0, NULL};
}
```